# what is the difference between Syncano class and SyncanoDashboard?

Tags: android, mbaas, syncano

What is the difference between `Syncano` class and `SyncanoDashboard` in declaration like that :

```
SyncanoDashboard syncano = new SyncanoDashboard(API_KEY, INSTANCE_NAME);
```

and

```
Syncano syncano = new Syncano(API_KEY, INSTANCE_NAME);
```

??

Comment: You should see the contents of the class

Answer (score 2):

Syncano Dashboard class is used to do all the actions that require Admin access level and your Account Key (you can find account key using this link: https://dashboard.syncano.io/#/account/authentication, see attached screenshot [Dashboard Account Key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOfVv.jpg))

So using Syncano class, you can add objects, update them, remove them, login/sign up your users, run public webhooks etc.

Using SyncanoDashboard class, you can do other things you usually would use Dashboard for - adding a new class, adding a Script, Trigger, Schedule etc - things that require Admin access, not just standard API Key.

Easy to check what eachlooking into source code:

- SyncanoDashboard.java - https://github.com/Syncano/syncano-android/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/syncano/library/SyncanoDashboard.java
- Syncano.java - https://github.com/Syncano/syncano-android/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/syncano/library/Syncano.java )

(disclaimer: I work for Syncano)